# 2digit multiplication on 8bit system

Tags: c, pic, multiplication

I'm looking for a way to multiply 2 numbers together (both 2 digits)
I'm programming in C and using a PIC18F4455 chip, as well as CCS compiler.
Here is the issue:

code:

```c
#include<18F4455.h>
#fuses HS,NOWDT,NOPROTECT,NOLVP
#device ICD=TRUE
#use delay(clock=5000000)
#include<lcd.c>  //LCD display source code
#include<kbd_xy.c> //keypad source code
void main(){
    char k;
    //
    //code to retrive keypad input and store in a and b values
    // 
    unsigned long c;
    unsigned int a=99;
    unsigned int b=1;
    while(b<99)
    {
        c=a*b;
        printf(lcd_putc,"%Ld",c);
        delay_ms(1000);
        lcd_putc('\f');
    }
}
```

The issue is that the numbers stored in c cannot exceed 256 due to the chip being 8bit.
so 99*1 gives 099, 99*2 gives 198, but 99*3 gives 41, note 99*3=297 which is 256+41 and so on...

I'm looking for a better way to get the true results, they are going to be displayed via LCD so if i end up with 4 variables each housing a digit that's O.K. by me.
if when i do 99*3 i get variables like c1=7 c2=9 c3=2 and c4=0 thats awesome

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. In C you must be able to multiply 99 by 99 and get 9801 without any problems irrespective of what the underlying hardware is and irrespective of how your C compiler leverages its functionality. If your compiler is not a compliant C compiler, well, at the very least say so and give people information on how it's different from a standard one.

Comment: Btw, it should be `%ld`, not `%Ld` if you're printing `long`. In your particular case it should be `%lu` since it's `unsigned long`.

Comment: I specified the compiler as well as stated that I am only allowed 8bit integers due to hardware constraints

Comment: Are you using the wrong compiler + chip combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own issue. It seems that by default any declared `int` in the CCS compiler is an `int8`.
SO the remedy was quite simple:

```c
#include<18F4455.h>
#fuses HS,NOWDT,NOPROTECT,NOLVP
#device ICD=TRUE
#use delay(clock=5000000)
#include<lcd.c>  //LCD display source code
#include<kbd_xy.c> //keypad source code
void main(){
    char k;
    //
    //code to retrive keypad input and store in a and b values
    // 
    int16 c;
    int16 a=99;
    int16 b=1;
    while(b<99)
    {
        c=a*b;
        printf(lcd_putc,"%Ld",c);
        delay_ms(1000);
        lcd_putc('\f');
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you configure your compiler so that plain ints are 16-bit by default as that's the minimum required size per the C standard and use either chars (int8's) or ints as appropriate for the task at hand.

Comment: Don't feel bad, this looks like some platform specific nonsense

Comment: yeah it's platform specific. due to being small hardware (8bit & 16bit micro controllers) just a hoop to jump through :/